Powershell and using a hash table to grab a 3rd value
I am trying to write a Pwoershell script to get the values/attributes for each objectID as shown below, from my research a hash table would work, but this appears to work as a key pair, I need to fetch the 3rd attribute i.e Role.

At this stage, a simply foreach loop printing all the 3 different dimension values would be ideal, In the example below, I can get the ObjectID and the type, but I need a way to get the Role for each objectID
Role: Administrator
Type: Group
ObjectID: 982c-4ed0-ac15-d52f357f01454ee96d4e

Example
$hash = @{
    '982c-4ed0-ac15-d52f357f01454ee96d4e' = 'Group'
    '4ed0-ac15-d52f357f' = 'ServicePrincipal'
}

$hash.getEnumerator() | foreach {
    Write-Host ("Key = " + $_.key + " and Value = " + $_.value);
}

Is it also possible to have this passed as a parameter to a PowerShell script file.
Thanks in advance.

The use of [pscutomobject] mklement0 suggested is likely the best option most of the time
But just for completion you can use a nested hashtable:
$HashCollection = @(
    @{
        ObjectId = '982c-4ed0-ac15-d52f357f01454ee96d4e'
        Values   = @{
            Type = 'Group'
            Role = 'Administrator'
        }
    },
    @{
        ObjectId = '4ed0-ac15-d52f357f'
        Values   = @{
            Type = 'ServicePrincipal'
            Role = 'Reader'
        }
    }
)

Though I suspect the use-cases are quite limited


Define your data as [pscustomobject]s and (initially) collect them in an array:
$objects = 
  @(
    [pscustomobject] @{ Role = 'Administrator'; Type = 'Group'; ObjectID = '982c-4ed0-ac15-d52f357f01454ee96d4e' },
    [pscustomobject] @{ Role = 'Reader'; Type = 'ServicePrincipal'; ObjectID = '4ed0-ac15-d52f357f' }
  )

Printing $objects to the display will give you a tabular representation:
Role          Type             ObjectID
----          ----             --------
Administrator Group            982c-4ed0-ac15-d52f357f01454ee96d4e
Reader        ServicePrincipal 4ed0-ac15-d52f357f

Alternatively, define them as ordered hashtables: [ordered] @{ Role = ... }, though their default display formatting will result in each key-value pair printing on its own line.

Then, if needed, collect the objects in a hashtable, keyed by their .ObjectId values:
$objectDictionary = @{}
$objects | ForEach-Object { $objectDictionary[$_.ObjectID] = $_ }

You can then retrieve a given object by its .ObjectID value, e.g.:
# -> [pscustomobject] @{ Role = 'Reader'; Type = 'ServicePrincipal'; ObjectID = '4ed0-ac15-d52f357f' }
$objectDictionary['4ed0-ac15-d52f357f']


Is it possible to pass the pscustomobject onto a Ps file, do you have an example of this please ?

@learner, a [pscustomobject] can be passed as an argument just like an instance of another data type. If you want to pass a literal, enclose it in (...). Also note that the answer you accepted is inconsistent with your question: it creates a different data structure.
